# jQuery element set to hidden, not catching with is visible due to AJAX delay

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I'm using the following code to monitor change events on two select menus. Based on selections made determines if a third element is displayed.

Because `.single_variation_wrap` has text being updated with AJAX first then it's display is toggled, if I don't wait for one second, the visibility of '.single_variation_wrap` is not caught at the right time.

So I set a delay to let AJAX fire and update the text, then the elements display is toggled, by the time that all finishes my conditional fires and see if the element is hidden or visible.

Is there a jQuery method to monitor for AJAX to finish so this can complete faster? There is nothing showing up in dev tools under Network - XHR.

```
$("#interface, #pa_input-current").change(function() {
    var wto;
    wto = setTimeout(function() {
        if ($(".single_variation_wrap").is(":visible")) {
            alert('visible');
        }
        else {
            alert('hidden');
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Can you just add a success to the AJAX and then put this code in there without the delay?

Comment: @jonmrich I thought about searching for the ajax function and using the success event but that may mean modifying core code. I was hoping there would be another method to begin checking visibility once ajax has finished

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by using a success function.

example of the success function in use:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
        if ($(".single_variation_wrap").is(":visible")) {
            alert('visible');
        } else {
            alert('hidden');
        }
    }});
});
```